# Django django-bootstrap-v5 works locally but failed with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap5' on AWS Elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bootstrap-5

I have a project that use the package: django-bootstrap-v5==1.0.11
everything works OK, but when I try to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk server I get the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap5'

And when I delete the 'bootstrap5' from my INSTALLED_APPS the server is up...
I'm new to Amazon EC2 service so not sure what is the write approach -
Are all packages allowed? If not how can I check which one allowed and how to manually use others?

will appreciate any help, Thanks!